# Self-written mapper on C#

Tags: c#, .net

I develop my own application. I would like to write a good and elegant mapper. My idea is to use an extension methods. Could you please rate the following solution. I use `Threading.Tasks.Result` because its the Main method. Normally I want to use `await`. I know that the `Project` method doesn't look the best, but I want to improve it somehow. Could you advise me something or give me some nugget name if this solution is unnecessary or wrong in your opinion?

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Application
{
    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserCopy
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserCopyTwo
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserWrong
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            var user = new User
            {
                Id = 15,
                Name = "John"
            };

            try
            {
                var usercopy = user.Map<UserCopy>().Result;
                Console.WriteLine(usercopy.Id + " " + usercopy.Name);

                var usercopy2 = user.Map<UserCopyTwo>().Result;
                Console.WriteLine(usercopy2.Id);

                var usercopy3 = user.Map<UserWrong>().Result;
                Console.WriteLine(usercopy3.Id);
            }
            catch(Exception ex) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); 
            }
            //15 John
            //15:John
            //One or more errors occurred. (No definition for mapping Application.User to Application.UserWrong)
        }
    }

    public static class Mapping
    {
        public static async Task<TDest> Map<TDest>(this Object copied)
        {
            var methods = typeof(Mapping).GetMethods();
            var method = methods.Where(m => m.GetParameters().Any(p => p.ParameterType.Equals(copied.GetType()))).First();
            MethodInfo genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TDest));
                        
            try
            {
                var task = Task.Run(() => (TDest)genericMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { copied })!);
                return await task;
            }
            catch (TargetInvocationException ex)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(ex.InnerException!.Message);
            }
        }


        public static T Project<T>(this User user) 
        {
            if (typeof(T).Equals(typeof(UserCopy)))
            {
                return (T)(object)new UserCopy
                { 
                    Id = user.Id.ToString(),
                    Name = user.Name
                };
            }
            if (typeof(T).Equals(typeof(UserCopyTwo)))
            {
                return (T)(object)new UserCopyTwo
                {
                    Id = user.Id.ToString() + ":" + user.Name
                };
            }
            throw new ArgumentException($"No definition for mapping {user.GetType()} to {typeof(T)}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which c#/.net version are you using? Since C#7.1 the [async main](https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/async-main-csharp/) is supported.

Comment: Why is your `Map` function async? What's the benefit here?

Comment: NET 6. Nice to know, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of already good mappers that have been built for .net ecosystem.   There are pros and cons using an automapper.  In my opinion as long as they just contain mapping one property to another and zero business logic, they are fine.  When you start mixing them together that's where they go off the rails.  I've joined teams where a ton of the business logic was in the mappings and I really disliked working on bugs that came out of that, this is where most of the hate for auto mappers come from.   Nick Chapsas did a YouTube video on comparing some of the more popular mapping packages https://youtu.be/U8gSdQN2jWI?si=Bo6yG3FbzJhdRqRM

The other option is to just do it by hand.  That is kind of what you are doing just making it more complicated than you need to.

Instead of having a generic Map and Project method just make an extension method class and make a method for each type

example

```
public static class UserMappings
{
    public static UserCopy ToUserCopy(this User user)
    {
        return new UserCopy
        {
            Id = user.Id.ToString(),
            Name = user.Name
        };
    }

    public static UserCopyTwo ToUserCopyTwo(this User user)
    {
        return new UserCopyTwo
        {
            Id = user.Id.ToString() + ":" + user.Name
        };
    }
}
```

No reflection needed and simple to follow and debug/create unit test for. I would recommend starting out writing code like above and if getting too much then look into mapping nugets.  Just remember to keep business logic out of mapping code.